# How can I set a value in a jquery dialog that is defined the first time the dialog closes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm simply trying to find a way to create a confirm dialog in jquery to use in place of the default confirm function in javascript.  I have a confirm dialog that's used to decide if I want to proceed without a given value in a form.  The whole program is here:

http://nowlin.com/testpop.php

The button code that's giving me a headache looks like this, but it may not be the button code.  I'm just learning jquery:

```
buttons: {
    'Yes': function() {
        document.getElementById("clicked").value = "true";
        creturn = true;
        $(this).dialog('close');
    },
    'No': function() {
        document.getElementById("clicked").value = "false";
        creturn = false;
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
}
```

This program works fine except for the confirm dialog.  I've tried setting a variable that has a global scope (creturn), and a DOM element from a hidden input (clicked.value), so that when the dialog closes I can tell which button was chosen.  The values both get set, but not until after the form Send button, where the onclick event is located, is hit a second time:

```
<button type=submit name=clicked value=true onclick='return chkreq("cfbform")'>Send</button>
```

The behavior is, if you enter an email address and no name, and hit the Send button, the confirm dialog pops up.  If you select Yes the dialog closes, but the form isn't submitted.  If you click the Send button a second time, the dialog pops up again, immediately closes on its own, and the form is submitted.  Clearly I'm missing something.

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would switch the button from type=submit to type=button (we can also drop the return)

```html
<button type=button name=clicked value=true onclick='chkreq("cfbform")'>Send</button>
```

and then use jQuery to submit the form when it passed validation.

```js
function chkreq(fid) {
// both values are set return true
    if (document.getElementById(fid).elements.namedItem("name").value.length > 0 &&
        document.getElementById(fid).elements.namedItem("email").value.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("clicked").value = "true";
        $('#' + fid).submit();
    }

    ...
}
```

And

```
buttons: {
    'Yes': function() {
        document.getElementById("clicked").value = "true";
        $('#' + fid).submit();
        $(this).dialog('close');
    },
    'No': function() {
        document.getElementById("clicked").value = "false";
        creturn = false;
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
}
```

For more info see https://api.jquery.com/submit/

The other option used on that page is binding to the submit event. With your override-able validation via the popup, I think the above code will be easier to implement.

Comment: Great answer.  You provided the piece of the puzzle that I missed.  I could get the confirmation dialog to submit the form when I clicked yes.  In fact, I had that commented out.  The problem was with a button type button, the check of required fields that didn't have to call the confirmation dialog, wouldn't submit the form when it returned true.  Actually submitting the form explicitly in the check function did it.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

using Submit buttons and binding click events to them and handling the click in jQuery could cause issues like your jquery gets called then the post pack gets called because of the submit.
I suggest change the type of the button from "submit" to "button" and give it a try.

Comment: I had tried using a button that was just a button, but when I clicked on Send, nothing happened because the form wasn't submitted.  However, that was close, since the interference by the submit button seems to have been part of the problem.  Thanks.